# Add custom control outside Outlok ribbon

Tags: c#, outlook-addin, ribbon

I'm new to develop Outlook add-in.
I want to write a custom attach file service. When user select attached files, my add-in will upload these files to my server. I want to show a control display upload progress. And I want put this control in same position with original attach file control.

My problem is, I cannot find any document about adding a control outside the Outlook robbin. Most documents guide me to add control to robbin, or a new tab.
See this picture below. I want to put my control in red rectangle position, or below the `Subject` field.

[image: Outlook add-in outside ribbon]

Is it possible to do? Thanks.

Comment: This? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668191.aspx

Comment: No, that is a basic tutorial. I have searched 1 week for this requirement, and view almost basic tutorials like your link.

Comment: why aren't you using a customized form?

Comment: Do you mean `customized form` is 'Outlook Form Region'? If I use `form region`, I must implemt many other controls of a compose email  form.

Answer (score 0):

I'd love some insight on how to accomplish this as well.  I've been wanting to do something similar in Word.